# Generate Unique Random Number based on UserID

Tags: c#

i got a code to generate random number.

```
public string Get8Digits()
 {
   var bytes = new byte[4];
   var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
   rng.GetBytes(bytes);
   uint random = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0) % 100000000;
   return String.Format("{0:D8}", random);
 }
```

but i am looking for a routine where i will pass user id and routine will generate unique random number based on userid. in my case user id may look like

```
a) 1,2,3,100,5000 
b) C0001,C0002,C0003,C0010
d) AL62YU,B1N36W,ZU21PQ etc
```

Comment: If you are repeatably generating a number based on `userId`, this number is by definition *not random*.  Perhaps you should explain what you're using this for?

Comment: OK, so in the worst case, assuming a base 36 scheme of 6 chars in the existing IDs, we're looking at a numberspace of 0-2176782335. This seems to be larger than the ID space of 0-100000000 implied in your first code snippet. Therefore, what you ask is plainly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but there is a flaw in your premise here:

Assuming you want a number with 8 digits, you will have `10^8 = 100'000'000 possible random numbers`. If you have a userID with just 6 characters, but including numbers and digits, you will have at least `36^6 = 2'176'782'336 possible combinations`.

You therefore obviously can't generate *unique* random numbers for each of your user IDs - at least not without expanding or changing the format of your identifier. Is that a viable option for you? Are there any other limitations on this ID number?

Comment: so please tell me what i need to change from my end. i want to generate random number which will be valid up to 5 sec. please discuss the changes what will be required.

Comment: Well clearly you need a number which can contain up to ´2'176'782'336´ different values. Alternatively, parhaps you could use letters and digits here too, and use a string instead of a number? Then you could use the same format as for the third type of User ID in your original question. Which format you can/would like to use is up to you. What are your limitations, if any? (ie. does it _have_ to be a number, and how big can it be)

Comment: it is on it can be string. so u just guide me how to achieve what i want...please come with sample code. thanks